# javascript: wait for async to complete

Tags: javascript

How do you wait for an asynch call to comlete before executing the next?

```js
    function fx1() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("1");
        }, 2000);

        fx1().done(function () {
            fx2();
        }
    }

    function fx2() {
        alert("2");  
    }
```

Comment: Just use an array as queue, fill the array with functions to execute, and have a handler function run the show.

Answer (score 0):

You can either manually provide a callback to the function:

```
function f1(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("1");
    callback();
  }, 2000);

f1(function() {
  alert("2");
});
```

Or make use of promises:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("1");
    resolve();
  }, 2000);
};

promise.then(function() {
  alert("2");
});
```

Using promises is probably the best idea, but working with them can be a bit tedious. Using third party libraries such as [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) can make working with them a lot easier.